# What is the correct verb for wire in this context?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I am trying to install or plug something with wire() at my place with my friend. So he is holding one end of the wire(and other one being plugged in) and I will give him instructions.

For example, there is a laptop the room and I need to connect it to a multi plug. Assuming the laptop power socket is on the right, there are two possible arrangements : wire in the back of the laptop to the plug or wire going in front of the screen.

So How do I specify the wire arrangement?

Should I say tell my friend

> **Bring** the wire in the laptop's **back/front**.
>   OR
>   Don't **run** the wire in the front of the the screen, it will block the view.

I think both of them are incorrect, but I am not very certain.

Comment: The second version (more exactly, *Don't run the wire in front of the screen,* with two unwanted *the*'s removed) is "natural" English. The first one isn't.

Comment: I'd probably change it to *cord* or *cable*.

Comment: Could you run that wire around the back so I won't have to fight with it all the time?

Comment: *Don't keep the cable in front of the screen, it'll hinder the view*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common to use run as the verb for routing wires.

"Run the wires behind the stereo so they will be out of sight."